# Spring ehcache not beeing use

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

I'm trying to setup a simple Spring cache ehcache for my MVC page. But it seems that the cache is never used. My function is executed each time.

```
@Cacheable(value="newsDocuments",key="#category")
public List<ProcessedDocument> getDocuments(String category, int   limit){
    List<ProcessedDocument> list = new ArrayList<ProcessedDocument>();
    System.out.println("getDocumetns!" + DateTime.now());
    list = getDBStuff(category,limit);
    return list;
}
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false"
              timeToIdleSeconds="10000" timeToLiveSeconds="60000"   overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache name="newsDocuments" timeToIdleSeconds="10000" timeToLiveSeconds="60000" maxElementsInMemory="10" eternal="false"    overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>
```

**spring config file**

```
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName="ProcessedDocuments")
public class ProcessedDocument implements Serializable {
//Just contains some simple get and set methods.
}
```

Each time getDocuments is being executed, it calls the db and outputs a new "getDocumetns!" + DateTime.now() in the console.

***The only "strange" I see in the debug is***

```
DEBUG: net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'newsDocuments'.
DEBUG: net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'newsDocuments'.
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 875 ms
```

Am I missing something every basic here?

Comment: Show your configuration of the cache, do you have `@EnableCaching` in your configuration? (or `<cache:annotation-driven />` when using xml).

Comment: Hi, yes i do use annotation-driven.                                                                                      <beans:bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
  <beans:property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
 </beans:bean>
 <!-- Ehcache library setup -->
 <beans:bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
  <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
  <beans:property name="shared" value="true"/>
 </beans:bean>

Comment: Don't add code as comments, add it to your question. Also looking from it you only have the cache setup, nothing related to enable the `@Cacheable`.

Comment: Where should I add EnableCaching pls? I was under the impression that EnableCaching  was used for Spring Applications and not websites.

Comment: And aren't you building a spring application? You are using the spring caching annotations, an annotation without a processor is doing nothing. So register it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for you and googled it .I found an example from Mkyong Ehcache example ;

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/

and I think it will useful for you. Because your **ehcache.xml:** not similar 
Mkyong's example  ehcache.xml.

I hope it will be useful for you..